# How to get FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', ... to work?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've tried to use FB.api to post something to my feed for hours now. I can't get it to work for me. I gave the permissions to the app. I can post to my feed with the PHP SDK but I have to use JavaScript.

```
<button onclick="doPost()">Post to Stream</button>

<script>
window.doPost = function() {
  FB.api(
    '/me/feed',
    'post',
    { body: 'Trying the Graph' },
    Log.info.bind('/me/feed POST callback')
  );
};
</script>
```

Can someone give me the example of a simple HTML page that uses FB.api to post to a feed?

Comment: Ah well, there is a reason: We can't use the Facebook UI.

Comment: hey I am even facing this error now and I am unable to fix it. could you please help me on it. Here is my code.http://dpaste.com/795673/ Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I got it working myself. I'm not sure what was wrong the first time as I started from scratch with a new HTML file. I hope it will help someone:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#" onClick="postToFacebook()">Post to Facebook</a>

    <script>
    function postToFacebook() {
        var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';

        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body, message: 'My message is ...' }, function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
          } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response);
          }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId  : 'YOUR APP ID GOES HERE',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks...
your post really help me to find out what's wrong with my code... :)

Comment: this script will open a new small window giving post option. What if i want to open this dialogue in the same window?

Answer (score 4):

I use this code on fb game-app 
and looks like this http://trupa.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/prscreenan.jpg

```
<a href="#" onClick="publishStory();" class="sendFeed"><br><font style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;padding-left:27px;">post to wall</font></a><br>
<script>
function publishStory() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'message name',
    caption: 'message caption ',
    description: 'description goes here',
    link: 'the url current page',
    picture: 'if you want to add an image'
  }, 
  function(response) {
    console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In first example you forgot "message" property. With out "message" you can post everyone, but not self.