# Decode Javascript Encoded Variables

Tags: javascript, facebook, decode

How do I decode encoded javascript variables like:

```
_0xa2bax2
_0xa2bax3
_0xa2bax5
```

**Edit**

I decoded most of it but there are still portions I can't decode:

```
var _0xa2bax2 = 'DESCRIPTION';
FB['api'](
    '/me/feed',
    'post',
    { message: _0xa2bax2 },
    function (_0xa2bax3) {}
);
```

Comment: What are these encoded by?  Are these variable names, or variable values?  Are you using some server-side language that is emitting this JavaScript?  Are you trying to reverse engineer some obfuscated JavaScript library?

Comment: I decoded most of it but there are still portions I can't decode:

var _0xa2bax2 = 'DESCRIPTION';
    FB['api']('/me/feed', 'post', {
        message: _0xa2bax2
    }, function (_0xa2bax3) {});
};

Answer (score 0):

From the code sample you provided in your comment (and I edited into your question), those appear to be just arbitrary variable names in the code.  Using the [code sample from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932880/how-to-get-fb-api-me-feed-post-to-work), they are probably translated roughly into something like this:

- _0xa2bax2 = message to post to the wall
- _0xa2bax3 = response from the post - can be used to check for error message from posting or retrieve the new Post ID
- _0xa2bax5 = no idea?? you don't have any examples...

See the [FaceBook Developers API page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) for more information.